# An efficient algorithm for factorising cyclotomic polynomial over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algorithms, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

I need to factor a cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(X)$ modulo $\mathbb{Z}_{p^e}$ where $p$ is a relatively small (at most 8 bits) prime number, and $e$ is a positive integer. As far as I know, the easiest way to achieve this is,

1. Factor $\Phi_m(X)$ modulo $\mathbb{Z}_p$ using Berlekamp algorithm or Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm.
2. Use Hensel lifting to lift the factors to $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$.

However, according to a research (https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800206.806394), the running time of Berlekemp algorithm for cyclotomic polynomials is super-polynomial. Indeed, my implementation using Hecke.jl library takes too much time to factor a high-degree cyclotomic polynomials. So, I was trying to devise an efficient method to factor a cyclotomic polynomial. Thankfully, we have a useful information that $\Phi_m(X) = (X-\zeta_{i_1})(X-\zeta_{i_2})\cdots(X-\zeta_{i_n})$ where $n = \phi(m)$ and $gcd(m, i_j) = 1~(1\le j \le n)$, and the Frobenius automorphism $X \mapsto X^p$ is the automorphism group for the finite fields $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/F_i(X)\cong GF(p^d)~(1\le i \le \ell)$ where $\Phi_m(X) = \prod_{i=1}^\ell F_i(X)$ where $p^d = 1\pmod m$ and $d \cdot \ell = n$.

Therefore, we can set $F_i(X) = (X-\zeta_{\gamma_i \cdot 1})(X-\zeta_{\gamma_i \cdot p})\cdots (X-\zeta_{\gamma_i \cdot p^{d-1}})$ where $\gamma_i \in \mathbb{Z}_m^{\times}/(p)$. I am stuck here since these roots of unity does not exist in the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, and therefore it is hard to compute the exact representation of this polynomial $F_i(X)$ modulo $p$. It would be really helpful if someone could help me out with this problem.

In addition, if I should use Berlekemp algorithm instead, how can you match the factors from the Berlekemp algorithm and $F_i(X)$'s above? (i.e. how would you know a polynomial factor obtained from the factoring algorithm is associated with certain roots of unity?)

To summarise,

0. Is there a direct method to factor $\Phi_m(X)$ modulo $p^e$ instead of factoring it modulo $p$ and then lift it to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^e}$?
1. How can one find the representation of the factors $F_i(X)$ of $\Phi_m(X)$ modulo $p$ using the roots of unity?
2. (Additional) If you are given the factors of $\Phi_m$ modulo $p$, how can you associate them with the corresponding roots of unity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually those roots of unity come into existence together with their minimal polynomial, so I don't quite understand exactly what you mean by Goals #1 and #2. Of course, if we have a splitting field of $\Phi_m(x)$ already at hand, and have identified a primitive $m$th root $\zeta$, your recipe for the polynomials $F_i(x)$ is available.

Comment: Particularly when $p=2$ it is quite efficient (IIRC I implemented it for moderate size $m$ back in the day) to factor $x^m-1$, $m$ odd, in $GF(2)[x]$ by finding the orthogonal idempotents associated with cyclic codes of length $m$. The algorithm is described in van Lint's older book on coding theory. If memory serves it was more or less equivalent to using Berlekamp, and used the idempotents coming from cyclotomic cosets as a starting point. If your search tells that the factorization is superpolynomial, what do you expect?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the answer. My questions can be rephrased to 'given an algebraic number, how to find the corresponding minimal polynomial' and 'given a set of algebraic number and a set of minimal polynomials, match them correspondingly'. I am not sure how can I implement it while I can understand it at heart.

Will check van Lint's book as well, thanks.